# SharePoint CSOM Query Keyword Filter On Date Time Type Column

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I am using the **CSOM SharePoint** client library fom a Desktop c# application to interact with SharePoint.

I would like the do a **query** based on a **date and time type column** being of a certain date time and to return the matching document data.

If I enter the text LastModifiedTime: 2019-11-19 into the SharePoint search box, results are returned so I know there is matching data in SharePoint.

If I set the **KeyWorkQuery** to be a query on a string based column the expected results are returned.

```
KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(context);
keywordQuery.QueryText =  @"author: ""Tom"" author: ""Bill"" FileType: ""txt""";
```

To filter on a column that is a datetime type I have tried the following and I am not getting the data back.
I suspect this is a format error in the query text and the query is being treated as a string, as opposed to being of type datetime,

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "LastModifiedTime:2019-11-19T09:28:25:ssZ";
keywordQuery.QueryText = "LastModifiedTime:2019-11-19T09:28:25";
keywordQuery.QueryText = "LastModifiedTime:2019-11-19";
```

Can the SharePoint client library be used to query on date time type based columns?

If so, what format does the QueryString need to be so that column can be filtered on?
Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the KQL examples it uses "=" instead of ":" for datetimes it seems. Try:

```
LastModifiedTime=today
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference

You could also try using a range of dates:

```
LastModifiedTime>=2019-01-01 AND LastModifiedTime<=2019-04-26
```

EDIT
The issue might be due to KQL not supporting an exact date filter. It has to be a range or special keyword option it seems.

As far as datetime string format your examples look to be supported.